# How to paste a text on non-pasteable (tap & hold pasting) text field?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.4-kitkat, root-access, samsung-galaxy-s-4, copy-paste

My problem is that I have no way to paste a text in an app because the app [doesn't allow tap & hold pasting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275299/how-to-disable-copy-paste-from-to-edittext). The keyboard I use (Google Keyboard) also does not have a clipboard button anywhere. The personal dictionary shortcut entry length is too short for what I'm trying to do and even if it were long enough, it doesn't work (doesn't even replace a simple "brb" with "be right back").

1. Can anyone suggest a way for me to keep using my Google Keyboard while being able to paste in a text field that doesn't allow for tap & hold pasting?
2. Is there a way to somehow add a clipboard button to my current (Google Keyboard) keyboard?

I ask these two questions as if there are simple answers to them because every single tool for a rooted phone boasts unlimited access to the user over your device, yet not a single tool that I've used has been able to provide me with a simple workaround to this simple issue of being able to paste in a text field that doesn't allow tap & hold paste.

I have a rooted Samsung Galaxy S4 on a CM11 ROM running Android 4.4.4 KitKat. I also badly want to keep my Google Keyboard, so if possible, I don't want to download another keyboard.

Comment: I'm thinking the question is still too broad. 1&2 is closely related, but 3 is not (copy-paste vs macro/automation). 4 is off-topic since it's development related. Consider removing 4 since it's off-topic, and post 3 as a new question.

Comment: Thanks I'll do that. Where should I post 4 though?

Comment: Currently, it's nowhere because it's very broad. However, for programming Q&A, it's [so]. Probably this question on SO can help you: [How to develop a soft keyboard for Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480715/how-to-develop-a-soft-keyboard-for-android)

Comment: I thought I could find a floating widget to paste a text, but surprisingly there's none... so the only workaround is (unfortunately) use another keyboard (e.g. Hacker's Keyboard) only for copy-paste shortcut. (not sure to put that as an answer, since it's not convenient)

Comment: I stumbled upon Hacker's Keyboard but it wasn't working out for me. Instead, I installed an app named "Clipboard Keyboard" that is very clean and allows me to easily paste large clippings of text in an efficient manner that isn't a nuisance.

Comment: Why was that post closed for "being too broad"? Where was it moved to?  I don't see how shutting it down without indication to where it's been moved is helpful... @Andrew T.